# Couldn't load Existing Source Map Error on Parcel

Tags: node.js, npm, parcel

I am using parcel as my module bundler and i ran into the following error after using it for some time. Below is an error i get.

```
Could not load existing sourcemap of "../../../node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js".
```

After this error is displayed it runs lots of codes on the terminal

[image]

i also managed to capture a screenshort of the error before the random strings started appearing on the screen.  How can i solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: this could be frustrating to debug.. can you copy all the codes that appear on the terminal and find the code around the 1688278 the column. The whole code that gets outputted should be mostly in a single line

Comment: Hi, @Panther i got a solution i decided to delete the node_modules folder and all cache files then ran npm install fresh. And the problem was solved. This becaue it started telling me that it cannot find some angular files yet i am not doing angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to Parcel V2 Solves The Error Checkout [Version 2](https://v2.parceljs.org/)